# Loop over web pages with recursion - function not handle first page

Tags: scala, selenium, recursion

So i have several web pages that i want to visit, each page has list of items that i want to count and then click next page button until the last page and return `List[Double]` (inside each page i need to parse some value and thats why the `Double` variable).

So i have this `isNextPageExist` function that return the next page `URL` in case it exist and `None` otherwise:

```
  def isNextPageExist(): Option[String] = {

  }
```

This function calculating the total amount of page:

```
def calculatePageValue(): Double = {

  }
```

And the recursion function:

```
  def getTotalValue(option: Option[String]): List[Double] = {

    option match {
      case Some(x) => {
        driver.get(isNextPageExist.get)
        calculatePageValue() :: getTotalValue(isNextPageExist)
      }

      case None => Nil
    }
  }
```

So this works fine except the fact that this this function not calculating the first page.
When i call this function i am inside the first page so i need to calculate this page and then move forward into the next page.

BTW i have another 2 function the return `Boolean`: `isFirstPage` and `isLastPage` but i didn't know if i need to use them.

Answer (score 0):

So from the sounds of it you've already sort of identified the issue.
You're already on the first page but the first thing your code calls is get next page.

Instead you should call calculatePageValue first.
So in your Some(x) case something like

```
val currentValue = calculatePageValue() 
driver.get(isNextPageExist.get)
currentValue :: getTotalValue(isNextPageExist)
```

EDIT:

Re-Looking at the code I'm confused about why it does not throw an exception.
isNextPageExist should return a None when on the last page. This should throw an Exception when driver.get(isNextPageExist.get) is called, perhaps this is why the last page is not being calculated (and the exception hidden).

Maybe try refactoring the code slightly to look like:

```
def getTotalValue(url: String): List[Double] = {
    driver.get(url)
    val currentValue = calculatePageValue()
    val nextValues: List[Double] = isNextPageExist.map{nextUrl =>
        getTotalValue(nextUrl)
    }.getOrElse(Nil)
    currentValues :: nextValues
}
```

Comment: Just to note on the machine I wrote this solution I do not have access to a scala compiler so there may be a typo or similar in the code.

Comment: Not typo but the line val nextValues: List[Double] = isNextPageExist2.map { nextUrl => getTotalValue(nextUrl) is running again and again and the first page is in loop

Comment: Made an Edit. I expect this was caused by not calling driver.get ever so the current page always stayed the same.
The getTotalValue will only ever be called if isNextPageExist returns a value.

Comment: Again first page is ignored

Comment: Then I feel  something more fundamental is going wrong. 
If you only pass in a single page which has no next values then driver loads the url passed in, calculates the value then returns it inside a list.

Comment: You think maybe i need to change my function signature ? do you have any other solution maybe ?

Comment: I'd suggest running through the code with a debugger and seeing what is being called when. If thats not possible run with different pages to test it. What happens when you pass in a page with no url, with 1 url, with two. add print statements. 

As for restructuring the code ideally you'd want two functions.
One which maps String => List[String] which gets you all the urls. And one which maps String => Double so you could calculate each page.

Also I expect this is classed as extended discussion and should be in 'chat' but I don't know how that works.